# Web socket connection does not get closed properly

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I am trying to build a logic where I try to reconnect websocket connection when it is disconnected. I wrote the following logic.

```
var webSocketObj = null;
var countForWebSocketReconnection = 0;
var intervalIdForWebSocket = "";

function webSocketConnection (message_arr) {
    if ("WebSocket" in window) {
        try {
            webSocketObj.onopen = null;
            webSocketObj.onmessage = null;
            webSocketObj.onclose = null;
            webSocketObj.onerror = null;

            webSocketObj.close();
        } catch (e) {
             console.log('try/catch around location update'+e);
        } finally {
            webSocketObj = new WebSocket(webSocketUrl);
            webSocketObj.onopen = function() {
                webSocketOpen(message_arr);
            };
            webSocketObj.onmessage = function (evt) {
                websocketMessage(evt);
            }
            webSocketObj.onclose = function() {               
                if(countForWebSocketReconnection>=6){
                    alert("Web-socket connection is terminated by the browser. Please reload the page.");
                    clearTimeout(intervalIdForWebSocket );
                    intervalIdForWebSocket = "";
                } else {
                    monitorIntervalIdForWebSocket = setTimeout(function(){
                        webSocketObj.onopen = null;
                        webSocketObj.onmessage = null;
                        webSocketObj.onclose = null;
                        webSocketObj.onerror = null;

                        webSocketObj.close();

                        webSocketConnection(message_arr);
                        countForWebSocketReconnection++;
                    }, 10000);
                }
            }
            webSocketObj.onerror = function(evt) {
               webSocketOnError(evt);
            }
           }
    } else {

    }
}
```

In case of any disconnection it try to reconnect 6 time. While trying so, it opens 6 connections(In case of 6 failed attempt to connect) as I monitored on Google Chrome console. Can someone suggest here what I am doing wrong or is there something wrong with my approach? It would be very helpful.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what's going wrong here. You said you want it to try to reconnect 6 times and then you say when it disconnects, it opens 6 new connections if it failed 6 times. That sounds like expected behavior. Or does it open them all at once? What about this is different then expected?

Comment: Yes I want to reconnect it 6 times but each time it try to reconnect a new connection is getting open with type as pending. I don't want any stale connection to remain alive.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: when the websocket connection closes, you try to reconnect 6 times, and then give up?